# Securing data in javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a JavaScript based chrome app ( a game ) and storing its leader-board in Google App Engine.

Whenever  a level is completed i am sending the user score to the GAE server to save user score and update the leader-board.

The ajax call looks like this

```
$.post( "someurl", { username: "John", time: "50" , level:"2" } );
```

Since the JavaScript will be residing in the users browser , How can i secure the user data to prevent from attack , as the request going from the app to GAE server can easily be monitored and manipulated.

Comment: Adding as comment rather than answer because it's a non-answer. You're really asking how to trust data submitted by untrusted sources, and it should be apparent from that phrasing that it's impossible to do this perfectly. There are three general approaches that mitigate the problem: first, server-side fraud detection; second, obfuscated and frequently-rotated client secrets to authenticate content with HMACs; and third, requiring sign-in so that you can punish bad users by deleting their accounts. None of these is perfect, and none works without ongoing engineering effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is actually deeper than you think.

First off, let's establish that very casual protections will not work: it takes one knowledgeable user to ruin your scoreboard and your day. But at some point there are diminishing returns, as you're not expecting an experienced hacker to deliberately hack a casual game's scoreboard.

Since you're making a Chrome App, your code, unless hidden away in a Native Client module, is in the open, with a convenient debugger supplied.

- Suppose you have a function `postScore(score)`, then an attacker can call it directly, and no matter what authentication or transport layer you're using it posts a tainted score.
- Suppose you have a function along the lines `postScore(gameState)` that calculates the score, possibly along with a token that depends on the state. It will be harder to hack, but you'll still be only verifying (server-side) against data sent. You'll need to be clever about the verification token for it to succeed.

The most tamper-proof method would be a verifiable log of the game states. *Think chess: what better way to validate a result in chess than a log of moves taken?* This will make it impossible to post outrageous scores.

This may be non-trivial to implement in realtime games, but frequently you can break game states into discrete events for which you can at least estimate the possibility of transitions. I.e. in a scrolling shooter it's unreasonable to log every command, but possible to log enemy kills; you can then verify that it's possible to kill enemies in a given sequence.

This, by the way, still opens way to copy someone else's result. That is difficult to protect from, though you can make a hacker's life miserable by running some sort of user-token-dependent cryptography on the log.

Another important consideration is that **sending verification data to the server means a lot of processing on the server**. This may burn through GAE quotas quickly, so you need some sort of DoS protection on the server too - too many requests from the same user (you should still be using user tokens) should be throttled. A sane idea would also be to only verify game logs for top-10 score contenders.

Comment: As a followup to this excellent answer, consider not doing anything at all. Unless you're providing a financial incentive for people to get high scores, you might be surprised to find that nobody bothers to hack your system. Granted, I've never written a top-10 title, but I have worried about fraudulent scores for my games, and never got around to protecting the leaderboard, and you know what? People were more interested in playing the game well than in hacking their scores.

Comment: Thanks Xan! Verifying the states for top-10 is the best idea , i can also obfuscate the script to make it harder for manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement an security layer into your applications.

So instead of sending the username (as a POST params which is easy to read/intercept) you can pass an authentication token into you request headers, which is way more secure, so into the server side, you read that authentication token (uniqueness), finds the user, and performs the action for your request.

you can increase the complexity/security of this approach easily. eg:

1 - you can set an expiration time for your authentication token
   2 - you can generate a new token every time the user signins and remove the old tokens, preventing users playing the same quest in the same account on multiple windows at the same time ? :P

Cheers

Answer (score -3):

You are using POST that is good.

More you can use "Session" for security.
For code security you can put your functions and other important code in some different php files and include them in main file. To keep your code visible from directly.

or you can get data as in json format may be very secure.

thanks